# How to change Program Name is UAC?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-installer, uac

I'm running msiexec.exe with the following code.

```
Process setupProc = new Process();
setupProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
setupProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
setupProc.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
setupProc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/i \"{0}\" /qn {1}",
sSetupFilePath, installerProperties);
setupProc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";         
setupProc.Start();
```

I want to change Program Name in the UAC, Is this possible at all to change program name.

Program name coming as "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe with the arguments I provide to run.

I just want to get rid of the arguments coming the rhe msiexec.exe.

I did lot of rnd but could not get possible solution and I think it is not possible.

Comment: No, because you really are running `msiexec.exe`. (Malware would take advantage of such a feature to trick users into running unsafe applications.)

Answer (score 0):

You should explain what your actual goal is. For example, if you wish to launch an MSI install from a standalone process, then give that process an elevation manifest so it will request elevation (your program name) and run elevated, and then use the CreateProcess version of your code, UseShellExecute=false.

Or if your code is already running elevated just set UseShellExecute=false.

In both cases msiexec will run elevated and not show elevation requests because you are firing it off in CreateProcess mode.

BTW, if you're running this from a custom action of an MSI install there's a good chance it will fail - this is really not recommended at all.